# DRBD Split Brain best scenario

Tags: drbd, splitbrain

I have 2 drbd node (primary/secondary) and I try to solve split brain without any lost data.

```
Running : Drbd(8.9.10-2), Pacemaker, Corosync, Postgresql
```

My auto solve config:

```
net {
    after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
    after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
    after-sb-2pri disconnect;
    data-integrity-alg md5;
}
```

How can I find last updated node? Is there any command or something like?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find last updated node? Is there any command or something like?

Unfortunately, you can't using DRBD itself. You could check your logs on both servers, and compare when each of them detected the split brain situation and therefor disconnected.

Or you mount the data on each server and compare from a client view of things. Then decide which server has the better data and discard everything on node B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Best.